# ifstream.open fails when inputting file name

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

I am writing a program in c++ that allows a user to enter the name of a file they want to open. However, whenever the program tries to open that file, even if the user inputs an existing file name and the file is in the same directory as the program, the file opening will fail. Why is this happening and how do I address this? I am using MacOS and writing this program in Visual Studio Code and compiling using Xcode's command line tools. The file I am trying to open is a .txt file. For additional background, I am in my first programming class and this is my first time using I/O streams.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
int main(){
    ifstream inStream; 
    ofstream outstream; 

    string filename1; 

    //accepting user input of file name 
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> filename1; 

    //** OPENING FILE ** 
    inStream.open(filename1); 
    //checking if open fails  
    if(inStream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

I have also tried writing this code so that the full path of the file is included in the open command, but that doesn't work, either.

Comment: Does the filename have spaces?

Comment: Also, try `cerr << strerror(errno);` when it fails.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Try using `std::getline` instead.

Comment: If its not missing spaces, did you add the file extension? Your file manager in Windows may hide the extension however you will need to type it for the open to succeed. If this is some other OS than windows the case of the filename may matter `readme.txt` is a different file from `README.txt` on a case sensitive file system. And finally the filename must be the name of a file in the current working directory. If it is not you must specify an absolute or relative path from that working directory. `c++` will not do any kind of searching for the file name you enter.

Comment: @Tim Roberts interesting, what OS and compiler do you use?

Comment: Windows and Linux.  There's no reason that should fail.  You know that capitalization matters on Linux and MacOS, right?